# Proving that a map is not a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I want to prove that the map $I \rightarrow I \times I$ where $0.a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}... \rightarrow (0.a_{1}a_{3}a_{5}..., 0.a_{2}a_{4}a_{6}...)$ is not a homeomorphism. Note that $I$ is the unit interval from $0$ to $1. My thought on this problem is that the reason it is not a homeomorphism is the fact that it is not surjective. I am unsure how I would write this as a proof if that is the right way to go. The help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A homeomorphism is defined as a *bijective* continuous map with continuous inverse.

Comment: I know. That is why if its not surjective, then its not bijective.

Comment: And thus you've proven that the given map is not a homeomorphism. (However, this map **is** surjective. It's not injective.)

Comment: That makes sense to me. I just wanted to mathematically show it though to prove it ;)

Comment: If your map wasn't surjective, then that **would** be a proof.

Comment: I guess what I am trying to say is that I would like to show it is not injective as you pointed out instead of just going straight to the fact that it isnt. In other words, show that if $f$ is the map, $f(a) = f(b) \Rightarrow a = b$ would fail.

Comment: Could you rewrite your question better? It is not really understandable. However if you want to show that a function is not injective you have to find to elements a,b such that if $a \neq b \implies f(a)=f(b)$ then your map is not injective ;)

Answer (score 1):

Your map *is* surjective. You need to show that it's not *injective*. (It's actually even further afield of being a homeomorphism: it's not even continuous.) So you want some element of $I \times I$ to be mapped to by two different elements of $I$.

**Hint**: Use that $0.0999... = 0.10000...$

Comment: Okay that makes sense. I see your argument. Quick question though. Are you sure it is surjective? I might be over thinking it but I just want to make sure. You can think of $I$ as the unit real line and $I \times I$ as a unit square if that makes sense. How does every element in the image get hit from some element in the pre image (unit real line)? I didnt think $I$ could cover it all.

Comment: @user128349 Every couple $(0.b_1b_2\dots,0.c_1c_2\dots)$ *gets hit* by $0.b_1c_1b_2c_2\dots$.